# re-resizable: only resize one side

Tags: reactjs, resizable

I'm using this [re-resizable](https://github.com/bokuweb/re-resizable) library to achieve the resize functionality. The requirement is to achieve the one-side resizing, which means if I resize from the right side of the div, only that side should expand to the right. The left side should stay in the same position.

I've read the docs and played around with the props but no luck. Thank you.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bessie-ejptco?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Do you need resizing from left too?

Comment: Yes. I need both. @Arkellys

Comment: It's like a trim tool in the video editing domain.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `handleClasses` prop to apply css class names to particular sides. For example if you want to resize from only the right side, you can do the following:

```
.pointer-events-none {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
<Resizable
  handleClasses={{
    top: "pointer-events-none",
    bottom: "pointer-events-none",
    left: "pointer-events-none",
    topRight: "pointer-events-none",
    bottomRight: "pointer-events-none",
    bottomLeft: "pointer-events-none",
    topLeft: "pointer-events-none",
  }}
>
  <YourComponent />
</Resizable>
```

By excluding the `right` property in the `handleClasses` object you are disabling the pointer events on every side except the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the way you trying to combine Draggable and Resizable. As Resizable only changes the width of the container you must adjust the position(either with translate or left) when resizing from left or right to simulate div stays in place.

But instead of re-resizable I suggest using [react-rnd](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd). I think it is from the same author so the interface should be similar but this is already implemented there, you only have to use one component like this:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-breeze-t4g4eg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Sorry but this is not true. i tested the work on local react app, commented out Draggable, commented out the props but still same issue

Comment: Still the same issue. Your `container` is `display: flex` and `just-content: center`. Which means the inner div will be centered, no matter of what. You change the width of a centered div, it will remain centered. If you wish you can still check my example, which is almost the same. Or implement the necessary logic to translate your trimmer div on resize event(which is already implemented in `react-rnd`)

Comment: I did not test your code. I tested the original code with "re-resizable" library.

Comment: It is up to you if use or not but this won't change the fact you have to implement your custom logic to position your trimmer div when resizing. But honestly I don't know why you should bother writing some code which is far from trivial than using a working and tested library which can do exactly what you want:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-rnd`, which does basically what you're doing here behind the scenes - only in a working implementation. If it doesn't work out of box for you, then you can at least study its code.

https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd/blob/36d3506f91375a0b4dbade1187a61038d5c4892b/src/index.tsx#L636-L685

https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd

Do note that the library hasn't been updated in a long while - so if you rely on it, you're going to be on your own for ongoing maintenance.